# .htaccess not including https or http in address bar

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I force `domain.co.nz` to redirect to `https://domain.co.nz`?

Currently using:

I am currently using the following .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sub-folder/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /sub-folder/index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+[^/])$ $1/ [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: you want it with www or none www? i mean https://www or only https://folderorwhatever

Comment: Seems its a chrome issue - firefox redirects domain.co.nz to https://

Answer (score 0):

Change the order:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^([^.]+[^/])$ $1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteBase /sub-folder/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /sub-folder/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Redirect first !

Comment: Thanks but its still not redirecting its strange